# java - Access variable in child class, given a superclass, from another class

Tags: java

Suppose I have 2 classes `ClassBottom1` and `ClassBottom2`, that extends classes `ClassMiddle1` and `ClassMiddle2` respectively, both of which extends another class `ClassTop`. I have 2 separate classes `ClassConstruct` and `ClassObserve`. `ClassObserve` extends `KeyAdapter`.

**ClassConstruct:**

```
LinkedList<ClassMiddle1> bottom1 = new LinkedList<ClassMiddle1>();
LinkedList<ClassMiddle2> bottom2 = new LinkedList<ClassMiddle2>();
```

Variables `bottom1` and `bottom2` contain a list of instances of `ClassBottom1` and `ClassBottom2` respectively.

Suppose `ClassBottom1` has a boolean variable called `boolVar` evaluating to `false`. How would I access this variable from:

**ClassObserver:**

```
private ClassConstruct construct;

public ClassObserver(ClassConstruct construct) {
    this.construct = construct;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < construct.bottom1.size(); i++) {
        construct.bottom1.get(i).boolVar = true; // throws an error, as boolvar does't exist in class (ClassMiddle1)
    }
}
```

How would I solve this problem?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: just cast it? if `ClassBottom1 extends ClassMiddle1` you can do the following: `((ClassBottom1)construct.bottom1.get(i)).boolVar = true`. Another question: do you ever hold something else then `ClassBottom1` in the list? if so, you may also want to use `instanceof` (or `ClassBottom1.class.isInstance`); if not: just set the type of `bottom1` to `LinkedList<ClassBottom1>`. Or use `val`/`var` ;-)

Comment: What happens if you have an subclass of ClassMiddle1 in bottom1 that does not have a boolVar property?

Comment: The variable `boolVar` is specific to `ClassBottom1`, and there will be other classes that extend from `ClassMiddle1` too. These other classes won't have the variable `boolVar` in them. I don't want to have a list for each class that extends from `ClassMiddle1`, that'll be a mess (for me at least). Is there still a way I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast it if you are sure that you have the implementation you need. But basically the compiler cannot know from the declaration that you ALWAYS will have `boolVar` there (if you would always have it it would be in the parent class).

If you need a specific property and ALL your list items will have a specific type then maybe you should create a list of ClassBottom1 and ClassBottom2 to enforce that only objects having that type and that property are inserted. Otherwise it is not enforced and you can get to error.

That's why we have generics in the first place. Otherwise it would be just lists of Objects (since everything is an object).

Comment: The variable `boolVar` is specific to `ClassBottom1`, and there will be other classes that extend from `ClassMiddle1` too. These other classes won't have the variable `boolVar`in them. I don't want to have a list for each class that extends from `ClassMiddle1`, that'll be a mess (for me at least). Is there still a way I can solve this?

Comment: yes you can check with instance of if a particular object is an instance of a class and then cast.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting in code, what other comments have suggested.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < construct.bottom1.size(); i++) {
        ClassMiddle1 m1 = construct.bottom1.get(i);
        if(m1 instanceof ClassBottom1)
            ((ClassBottom1)m1).boolVar = true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `ClassMiddle1` cannot be an instance of `ClassBottom1` but `ClassBottom1` can be an instance of `ClassMiddle1`. That's the wrong direction of hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You just have access to your variable `boolVar` directly from an instance of `ClassBottom1` or a subclass of `ClassBottom1`.

Casting won't be a solution because your `ClassMiddle` is not an instance of `ClassBottom1` or a subclass of that.

```
// will throw a ClassCastException
((ClassBottom1) construct.bottom1.get(i)).boolVar = true;
```

Maybe, you can redeclare your list as `LinkedList<ClassBottom1>` or rethink about your hierarchy?
Then you will be able to access your variable `boolVar`.

Comment: OP has mentioned `ClassBottom1` extends `ClassMiddle1`. and obj of type `ClassMiddle1` (base class) can be casted to `ClassBottom1` (child class)

Comment: "Suppose I have 2 classes ClassBottom1 and ClassBottom2, that extends classes ClassMiddle1 and ClassMiddle2 respectively". -> `ClassBottom1 extends ClassMiddle1`. That means, you cannot access `boolVar` from `ClassMiddle1`. Or am i wrong? :P

Comment: You can't access `boolVar ` from an object of type `ClassMiddle1` unless it is type-casted to `ClassBottom1`, if it can be.